# How to force the user to not send a property as null, even it is nullable

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to force the user not to send a property in JSON string if it is null, even if it is nullable.

Basically:

```
Data { "NullableVariable": "Nullable Value" }
```

Correct.

```
Data {  }
```

Correct.

```
Data { "NullableVariable": null }
```

Incorrect.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Your question is "how to skip serialization of properties with `null` value".

Comment: Check it it's null, if it is throw an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force an exception to be thrown if and only if a property is present with a null value by setting [`JsonPropertyAttribute.Required`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyRequired.htm) to [`Required.DisallowNull`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Required.htm), which means

> The property is not required but it cannot be a null value.

Thus your type would look like:

```
public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string NullableVariable { get; set; }
}
```

Notes:

- When `Required.DisallowNull` is set, attempting to deserialize the following into the `Data` type above will throw an exception:

  ```
  {"NullableVariable":null}
  ```

  While the following will all deserialize successfully:

  ```
  {}
  {"NullableVariable":""}
  {"NullableVariable":"Nullable Value"}
  ```
- In order to successfully serialize the type when `NullableVariable` is `null`, you need to set [`JsonProperty.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyPropertyLevelSetting.htm).  This is because `Required.DisallowNull` will cause an exception to be thrown *during serialization* when the nullable member is null; `NullValueHandling.Ignore` suppresses this (as well as the output of the null value).
- `Required.DisallowNull` was added in [Json.NET 8.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/8.0.1) so be sure you are using this version or later.

Comment: Thanks @dbc, I have an earlier version so I won't be able to implement the solution, however I marked as an answer as it is the solution.